# Append a Nodelist result in a form

Tags: javascript, laravel, nodes

I have this function:

```
function selectCheckedAnswer(){
        
        var checkbox_checked = document.querySelectorAll('input[id="check"]:checked');
        var form = document.getElementById('formtosubmit');
        for (let i = 0; i < checkbox_checked.length; i++) {
            let item = checkbox_checked[i];
            form.appendChild(item);
        }
}
```

It is not working as expected. When debugging, there are generated one form to each checkbox checked. (because I inserted the form inside of the For loop, I know)

When I debug the code above, 2 forms are being sent to the controller
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrspG.png)

...but I just get 1 of the forms and 1 checked checkbox:
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKod8.png)

What I need is to send only one form with the checkboxes selected to  the controller.

Comment: Shouldn’t it be `let item = checkboxes_checked[i];`?

Comment: The code should work: what is not working for you, and what results do you expect vs what you're getting now?

Comment: That's because your form has the same IDs. ID must be unique.

Comment: Nice! Thank you....But I still don't know what should I do lol

Comment: Don’t use duplicate IDs

Answer (score -2):

I think you are looking for this:

```
var checkbox_checked = document.querySelectorAll('input[id="check"]:checked');
var form = document.getElementById('formtosubmit');

checkbox_checked.forEach(element => {
   form.innerHTML += element.innerHTML;
});
```

Comment: Sorry, this solution did not work. I couldn't get any data from it.